# Which one is better practice: To pass the whole list of objects to a method, or to make the new instance of list of summarized objects?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

My Question is when i am having list of objects, should i pass the entire list to a methods in another layer or should i have another model and make the new list of it?

```
namespace Model
{
  Public Class class2
   {
     blah blah properties
   }
  Public Class Person
   {
     public string firstname { get; set; }
     public string lastname {get; set;}
     public int age {get; set;}
     public Datetime regDate {get; set;}
     public class2 SomeClass{get; set;}
   }
}

Namespace Service
{ 
  Namespace Model
   {
    public class LogPerson
    {
      public string firstName {get; set;}
      public string lastName {get; set;}
      public int age {get; set;}
    }
   }

public static class Log
 {
    //Method1
    public void Log(List<Person> persons)
      { 
         LogProvider.Log(Persons.Select(p=> new LogPerson{ p.firstName,   p.lastname, p.age}).ToList());
      }

     //Method2
     public void Log(List<LogPerson> persons)
     {
        LogProvider.Log(persons);
     }
}
```

As i showed above, is it good practice to pass the complete list of persons object (Log provider needs only firstname,lastname and age) or using method2 which needs the LogPerson object from the beginning.

I do not need opinions, what i need is,according to separation of concerns, which one is right way ?

Comment: You don't need opinions but an opinion? You do realize that this question *is* opinion based? At best, the answer depends. *Why* create copies of objects that you only want to log? Why hard-code the type in the Log method? Why pass a List<T> instead of IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: I did not explain my question clearly? accepted. but i do not need opinion,

Comment: Change the list to IEnumerable, doesnt make any changes. i meant shall i make the LogPerson list out of the log scope or not?

Comment: Wrong question and changing to IEnumerable matters *a lot*. IEnumerable is lazily evaluated. `ToList()` though forces an early evaluation. Plus, you limit callers to use a specific container. Besides, *why* a List if you don't intend to modify it?

Comment: Besides, *why* hard-code the class to log? That's a far more important question than asking what that hard-coded class will look like. There are a *lot* of logging frameworks, none of which forces a specific structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, i did not get my answer. I am aware of logging frameworks, what i am not aware of the correct way of passing the list of huge objects to another layer, should i make the new instance outside of my logging layer or inside of it? just inside or outside and why? (log layer is just an example  of shwing another layer in my demonstration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define an interface which has the properties you require to log, you can have only one model:

```
// keep in a separate, shared assembly
public interface ILoggablePerson {
  string firstName {get; set;}
  string lastName {get; set;}
  int age {get; set;}
}
```

then

```
 public void Log(IEnumerable<ILoggablePerson> people)
 {
    LogProvider.Log(persons);
 }
```

(note using IEnumerable instead of a List: this means the argument can be lazy evaluated [if required] and doesn't tie the method consumer to a particular data structure)

Finally, your Person class just has to add that interface to its declaration:

```
public class Person : ILoggablePerson
```

and then you can just pass in Person objects to your logger class:

```
Log.Log(new Person[] { ... }); // etc.
```

**Edit following comment**

Here's an example of how I might go about this: separation of concerns is still  provided by interfaces, just using dependency injection, provider and factory patterns... comments inline, hope it helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Service;
using Model;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var carLogger = Logger.Default(new Model.CarLogEntryProvider()); // generic type inference
            // want to log to a file? => Logger.File(@"c:\file path", new Model.CarLogEntryProvider()); 

            var personLogger = Logger.Default(new Model.PersonLogger());

            Car c1 = new Car() { Make = "Toyota", Registration = "ABC123" };
            Car c2 = new Car() { Make = "Toyota", Registration = "ABX127" };

            carLogger.AddEntries(new Car[] { c1, c2 });

            Person p1 = new Person() { Age = 21, FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Baloney" };
            Person p2 = new Person() { Age = 31, FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "O'Doherty" };

            personLogger.AddEntry(p1);
            personLogger.AddEntry(p2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

// model namespace knows how the model works and can make the decision of how its types are logged
// by implementing ILogEntryProvider as required: can even combine fields, add additional fields (eg timestamp) etc.
namespace Model
{

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Registration { get; set; }
    }

    // knows how to log a Car as required by this namespace: another system can implement this differently
    class CarLogEntryProvider : ILogEntryProvider<Car>
    {

        public ILogEntry GetLogEntry(Car car)
        {
            var result = new BasicLogEntry(); // can use a ThreadSafeLogEntry if application is multi-threaded
            result.Values["make"] = car.Make;
            result.Values["reg"] = car.Registration;
            return result;
        }
    }

    // knows how to log a Car as required by this namespace: another system can implement this differently
    class PersonLogger : ILogEntryProvider<Person>
    {
        public ILogEntry GetLogEntry(Person person)
        {
            var result = new BasicLogEntry(); // can use a ThreadSafeLogEntry if application is multi-threaded
            result.Values["age"] = person.Age.ToString();
            result.Values["surname"] = person.LastName;
            return result;
        }
    }
}

// service namespace has no knowledge of the model, it just provides interfaces for the model to provide
namespace Service
{
    public interface ILogEntry {
        IDictionary<string, string> Values { get; }
    }

    public interface ILogEntryProvider<T>
    {
        // can add any other properties here for fields which are always required

        ILogEntry GetLogEntry(T itemToLog);
    }


    public class ThreadSafeLogEntry : ILogEntry
    {
        public ThreadSafeLogEntry() { Values = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(); }

        public IDictionary<string, string> Values
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class BasicLogEntry : ILogEntry
    {
        public BasicLogEntry() { Values = new Dictionary<string, string>(); }

        public IDictionary<string, string> Values
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public interface ILogger<T>
    {
        void AddEntry(T item);
        void AddEntries(IEnumerable<T> items);
    }

    // factory pattern
    public static class Logger
    {
        public static ILogger<T> Default<T>(ILogEntryProvider<T> entryProvider)
        {
            return new ConsoleLogger<T>(entryProvider);
        }

        // create other methods here as required, all returning type ILogger<T>
        // eg:  public static ILogger<T> File(string filePath, ILogEntryProvider<T> entryProvider) { ... }
    }

    class ConsoleLogger<T> : ILogger<T>
    {
        private ILogEntryProvider<T> logEntryProvider;

        public ConsoleLogger(ILogEntryProvider<T> logEntryProvider)  // dependency injection
        {
            if (logEntryProvider == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            this.logEntryProvider = logEntryProvider;
        }

        void ILogger<T>.AddEntry(T item)    // explicit interface implementation: discourage use of this class in a fashion which doesn't treat it as an interface type
        {
            ((ILogger<T>)this).AddEntries(new T[] { item });
        }

        void ILogger<T>.AddEntries(IEnumerable<T> items)    // explicit interface implementation: discourage use of this class in a fashion which doesn't treat it as an interface type
        {
            var entries = items.Select(item => logEntryProvider.GetLogEntry(item))
                .Where(anyEntry => anyEntry != null) // perhaps a different behaviour required here...
                    .Select(nonNullEntry => nonNullEntry.Values);

            foreach(var entry in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New Entry: {0}", typeof(T).Name);
                foreach(var property in entry.Keys)
                {
                    // record each string pair etc. etc
                    string propertyValue = entry[property];
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = \"{1}\"", property, propertyValue);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        // TO DO: create an async pattern method:
        // public static Task AddEntryAsync<T>(ILogEntryProvider<T> adapterFunc, IEnumerable<T> items) { .... }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. Do you need setters in the interface?

Comment: Good one, but lets say i can not change the Person class and implement ILoggablePerson.

Comment: @richard no, I just copied his class.

Comment: @behzad will get back to you tomorrow

Comment: @Behzad updated - hope it helps.

Comment: @Nathan good explanation but different approach. so you are saying no need to have another Person class and pass the entire object to the logger method. just one question, what if the person object is huge, would you make any changes to your code?

Comment: @behzad might be sensible to implement an async method on ILogger<T> and use that for file/network target implementations of ILogger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer in regards to separation of concerns, if you don't need the properties in what you are passing to, then creating another model and a new list of it is the way to go.

This would separate the concerns of the layers. Layer 2 is not concerned about the unneeded properties of layer 1.